# TypeScript does not check a React.Component's propTypes, how could I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';

interface ITestProps {
  dir: string,
  className?: string,
};

class Test extends React.Component<ITestProps, {}> {
  static propTypes = {
    dir: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    // look here here here here here here here here here
    xxx: PropTypes.string // not ok, xxx is not in ITestProps
    // there should be an error
  };

  render() {
    return <div>test</div>;
  }
}

export default Test;
```

xxx is not in ITestProps, I believe there should be an error.
But I didn't see any error.

Comment: Why are you using propTypes at all if you're specifying them with TypeScript?

Comment: That's fine for an independent project, but if you're writing a library that's consumed in JavaScript externally, you'll get no type checking

Comment: @FrankerZ Because I am writing a UI framework. There is no guarantee that the developers who is using my UI framework use TypeScript too. They may use JavaScript. So runtime checking is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

PropTypes is ReactJS (plain Javascript) way to check types at runtime. TypeScript works similarly, but it check types earlier - at design time. Using both is redundant and it doesn’t talk to each other.

It is better to use TypeScript than PropTypes when building complex application or in the team.

And btw. your interface says that `dir` can be `a`, `b` or `undefined`, but in propTypes it is required.

Comment: yep, but ignore dir please. The point is xxx should trigger an error, I think so.